# OSRM Isochrone - straight/square edges

Tags: r, openstreetmap, isochrone, open-source-routing-machine, docker

I am calculating 1 hour cycling distance using osrmIsochrone in R and Docker. I have noticed that the polygons have square/straight edges. (see below example) [image: Cycling isochrone from Roskilde, Denmark]

Increasing the res even to high values (200+) still produces this effect. I've had a look at other isochrone maps and tried out some online apps, and this result still seems unusual. I guess what I'd like to know is 1) is there a way to minimise this effect and 2) is this a problem?

In terms of code here is what I am running ([on the denmark latest map from geofabrik](https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/denmark.html)):

```
iso <- osrmIsochrone(loc = c(12.0878, 55.6419),
                     breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 60, length.out = 2), res = 50)
iso <- st_as_sf(iso)

iso_map <- leaflet() %>% 
  setView(lng = 12.0878, lat = 55.6419, zoom = 11) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron", group="Greyscale") %>% 
  addPolygons(data = iso)
iso_map
```

Comment: Can you do a query to OSRM to get just the roads/paths/lines accessible in that 1h time? Isochrone *polygons* can be hard to generate when the roads are sparse and maybe this is the best it can do. A map zooming into the accessible lines overlaid with the isochrone polygon might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I think this would be pretty plausible given the area with the straight edges appear out the outskirts of the city center. I'll see if I can produce such a map.

Comment: But it does also look a bit like your polygon has been cropped to a square bounding box...